# Modulus function 's differentiability

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I show f(x ) =  |x |  + | x -1 | is not differentiable at x =0 by using the conventional " limits " method ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Near $0$, $x-1<0$ and therefore $f(x)=|x|-(x-1)=|x|-x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of a derivative as a limit $f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Show that the left limit (negative $h$) differs from the right limit (positive $h$).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
You can write
$$f(x)=|x|+|x-1|=\begin{cases}-2x+1 & \text{ if } x < 0\\1& \text{ if } 0 \leq x < 1\\2x-1 & \text{ if } x \geq 1.\end{cases}$$
Now use the limit definition of the derivative near $x=0$.
$$f^{'}(0+)=\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} \text{ and } f^{'}(0-)=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the first part ! How did you get  f(x) = { -2x+1 if x<0  , 1 if 0,,<= x<1 , 2x-1 if x>= 1 . As in , how did you derive? I'm new to this concept so please help !

Comment: @Bharathi A I am using the definition of the absolute value function that says that $|x-a|=(x-a)$ if $x \geq a$ and $|x-a|=-(x-a)$ if $x <a$. Since we have two such functions $|x|$ and $|x-1|$ involved, hence two values of $a$, namely $0$ and $1$ where changes will take place.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the Function y = |x| into two functions: See:
  1. y = -x from -∞ to 0 AND
  2. y = x from 0 to ∞ \
So that would mean that you have two different grades at the same x-Location what is not possible. Try it out on your given function!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).